# A contradiction arising due to set-builder form.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, notation

I have noticed a kind of contradiction arising due to set-builder form involving universal set$(U)$ while I was performing operations on set theory.

Here it is -

> Let us consider an arbitrary non-empty set $B$.
>   Then, $B = \{x : x \in B\} = \{x : x \in B \wedge x \in U\} = \{x : x \in B \cap U\} = \{x : x \in U\} = U$

But this is contradiction as $B \not= U$.
Instead  $B \subseteq U$.

Is it really a contradiction or my misconception ?

A detailed explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Can you start with a detailed explanation of your argument?

Comment: The third equality is a blunder.

Comment: "I have noticed a kind of contradiction arising due to set-builder form involving universal set($U$) while I was performing operations on set theory." Then I would advise you to stop performing operations on set theory.

Comment: What's a blunder is going from $B\cap U$ to $U$; $B\cap U=B$.

Comment: Why can't we consider $B \cap U = U$ instead of $B \cap U = B$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "consider"? You may consider $2+2=5$, but $2+2$ is actually equal to $4$, and $B\cap U$ is equal to $B$.

Comment: I also dont question on 'intersection' but instead on the notation of the set builder form.

Comment: This contradiction is arising as we dont apply the symbol of 'implies ($\rightarrow$)' after every step while performing operations by set builder form instead we use 'equality($=$)'.

Comment: “$x\in B\cap U\rightarrow x\in U$” tells you that if something is in $B\cap U$, then it is also in $U$. But when you assert that $B\cap U = U$, you are asserting **more**: you are also asserting that $x\in U\rightarrow x\in B\cap U$. And that implication is false. In other words, what you say “we can consider” is $B\cap U\subseteq U$, **not** $B\cap U=U$.

Comment: The contradiction is arising from the fact that you are asserting the **false** claim that $B\cap U = U$. By asserting that, you are in fact asserting that $B=U$. So your conclusion comes from your faulty assertion, not from anything else.

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with “we don’t apply the symbol of ‘implies’ after every set”, and it has **nothing** to do with set builder notation. It has to do with you making an error in the fifth step; nothing more, and nothing less.

Comment: Hmm, You messed up the Union and Intersection Notations, and used the wrong one in the wrong place. $B \cup U = U$, **not** $B \cap U$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As has been explained in the comments *(and if one of the original commenters adds an answer, I'll delete this one)*, the error is not a subtle logical issue but rather an intersection calculation.

You ask,

> Why can't we consider $B\cap U=U$ instead of $B\cap U=B$?

Well, the answer is: the first one is **not necessarily true** given our hypotheses on $B$ and $U$, while the second one is **necessarily true** given those hypotheses. I suspect the special character of $U$ (= the universal set) is making this more confusing than it should be.

Forgetting about universal sets, remember that whenever $X\subseteq Y$ we have $X\cap Y=X$, but we do **not** necessarily have $X\cap Y=Y$ (indeed, we won't unless $X=Y$). For example, take $X=\{1\}, Y=\{1,2\}$; we have $$\{1\}\cap \{1,2\}=\{1\}\quad\mbox{but}\quad\{1\}\cap\{1,2\}\not=\{1,2\}.$$

---

Of course the universal set *does* pose [serious issues](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/), and [the usual choice of axioms for set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) in fact prohibits such an object *(although some [other set theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations) allow it at the cost of weakening other axioms)*; but that's irrelevant to the particular issue here, which is really just an issue with subsets and intersections.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake might originate from a lack of familiarity with the propositional constant "***t***".

The sentence " x belongs to U " is a tautology ,  whatever x might be ( since, the defintion of the universal set means that any element you are considering belongs to the universal set).

Now, in propositional logic there is a propositional constant denoted by " ***t***" which is defined as : " truth" , "the tautology" , the proposition that is equivalent to any tautology.

Remark : there is also a propositional constant called  : " ***f***" " false" ( and that is defined as : the proposition that is equivalent to any antilogy.

Now, propositional logic tells you that, for any proposition P :

(P& ***t***)  is equivalent to P.

This is " identity law for tautologies" 
( http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-laws-of-propositional-logic , see also Lipschutz, Schaum's outline of set theory, at *archive.org*)

Explanation : in order a conjunction to be true, both propositions have to be true; since ***t*** is true in all possible case ( being a tautology), everything depends on the truth value of P: if P is true the whole conjunction in true, if P is false, the whole conjunction is false.

With this in mind, what is the set : B Inter U ?

B Inter U = { x | x belongs to B & x belongs to U }

But, as we said,  the sentence " x belongs to U " is equivalent to ***t*** .

So,

B Inter U

= { x | x belongs to B & x belongs to U }

= { x | x belongs to B & ***t*** }

= { x | x belongs to B}

= B

Comment: Why downvote? I'm curious.